# What's the difference between "Foo" and "Foo.class"?

Tags: ruby

Shouldn't these be the same?

```
p String.ancestors
p String.class.ancestors
```

instead I get:

```
[String, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
[Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

### TL;DR

> Shouldn't these be the same?

No, they shouldn't, why?

### Full answer

Difference between `Foo` and `Foo.class` is the same as between `f` and `f.class`

```
class Foo; end

f = Foo.new

f # => #<Foo:0x007ff289849170>
f.class # => Foo

Foo # => Foo
Foo.class # => Class
```

`Foo` is an object, and `Foo.class` is its class.

The hierarchy for classes and classes-of-classes forks, as you can see, at `Object`. Because everything in ruby is an object (*except for blocks :)*). But it doesn't have to be this way, it was just Matz' design decision (*I guess it was Matz*). In some languages these are two completely separate non-intersecting hierarchies. You don't mix objects and their classes. It's like mixing sweet and square things.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not optimized to make the minimal comparison. Instead of comparing:

```
String.ancestors
String.class.ancestors
```

you should compare:

```
String
String.class
```

And these are equivalent to:

```
String
Class
```

because `String` is an instance of `Class`. And since `String` and `Class` are different, there is no reason their `ancestors` should be the same.